# Generate Contour Given X, Y and Z vectors

Tags: matlab

Given 3 vector-pair, `X`, `Y` and `Z`, how to generate the contour? I understand that we need to make use of the [`contour`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html) plot. But the thing is that we need to pass in a 2x2 matrix for this argument, which presumably, is a matrix of Z corresponding to each X,Y pair. But this would mean that I have to go extra miles to create such a matrix by using `griddata` interpolation first before talking about contour generation.

Is there any other more succinct method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use the [Tricontour](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10408-contours-for-triangular-grids) tool. It is found on the file exchange (on Matlab Central.) This does the contouring as you desire directly, without forcing you to use meshgrid and griddata.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use tricontour for 3 arrays X, Y, Z?

Comment: @adrianp: Did I figure it out? It is pretty east to use, even trivial. Read the help. What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

MATLAB addresses this need of yours fairly succinctly.

What you need to do is use `meshgrid` to two-dimensionalize your `X` and `Y` vectors. Here is a simple example to demonstrate how to generate a contour plot of `z = sin (x^2 + x*y^2)`:

```
x = -10:0.1:10;
y = -10:0.1:10;
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = sin(x.^2+x.*y.^2);
contour(x,y,z)
```

Note the use of the `.^` and `.*` notations, which forces MATLAB to conduct an element-by-element evaluation of the `z` matrix, making it 2D in the process.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have data such as:

x1, y1, z1;
x2, y2, z2;
x3, y3, z3; ...

and you don't know the function for z. i.e. almost all real data. This isn't helpful.