# MATLAB: Make matrix from two variables and plot contour from third variable

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, contour

I have 3 variables (`x`, `y`, `z`) each in a 192x1 vector. The data is all random and sometimes has missing values (NaNs).
I would like to plot variable `c` against the other two variables `x` and `y` as contour plot (`x` on the x-axis, `y` on the y-axis, and `z` making up the contour lines).

My biggest problem is making up the 192x192 matrix for `x` and `y` because `x` and `y` consist of random data. I have tried to use GRIDDATA, Delaunay, and TriScatteredInterp but they did not work because I have NaNs in my data.
Does anyone know what I can do? If there was a way that I could return the matrix of `x` vs `y` from the scatter plot of `x` and `y` then my problem would be solved.

#### Example code

```
x=rand(192,1);
y=rand(192,1);
z=rand(192,1);

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
contour(X,Y,z);
```

> ??? Error using ==> contour at 74
> Z must be size 2x2 or greater.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733834/generate-contour-given-x-y-and-z-vectors

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I had already tried the suggestions in that link but they don't work because my data has NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you going to do with NaNs? Do they contain any additional information to draw the contour plot? Cannot you just remove them?

```
idx = any(isnan([x y z]),2);
x(idx)=[];
y(idx)=[];
z(idx)=[];
```

Then you can apply solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733834/generate-contour-given-x-y-and-z-vectors). The missing data will be interpreted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the ature of contour plots, the problem is with size of the matrix z. If you debug your code you see that after calling meshgrid, X and Y become of size 192 x 192. Simply change the following line and it will work! Let me know if the problem was solved ;)

```
z=rand(192,192);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This works for the random samples. How can I apply this to my real data for the z variable? I would like to end up with a graph like the first graph in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201701/maybe-matrix-plot . Thanks again.